# Object shows properties but accessing them returns undefined

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a game, and I've got a module that returns the keys currently being pressed via jQuery. No problems there. The problem comes when I attempt to access the keys pressed:

```
var Keys = require('./lib/keys')

Player.prototype.update = function () {
    Keys(function (err, keydown) {
        console.log(keydown, keydown['w']);
        /* // To move a player up, for example:
          if (keydown['w']) {
            this.y += this.speed;
          }            
        */
    });
};
```

And the console shows that what keys are pressed, but attempting to access one gives me an undefined instead of true.

```
Object    undefined
s: true
w: true
x: true
__proto__: Object
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Update: key module

```
var $ = require('./jquery')

var Keys = function (callback) {
  var keydown = {};

  function keyName(event) {
    return String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
  }

  $(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    keydown[keyName(event)] = true;
    return false;
  });

  $(document).bind('keyup', function (event) {
    return false;
  });

  callback(null, keydown);
}

module.exports = Keys;
```

/***************************
*      UPDATE      ***
*********************/

This is the final fix:

./lib/keys.js
    var $ = require('./jquery')

```
var Keys = function () {
  this.keydown = {};

  var keyName = function (event) {
    return String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
  }

  var self = this;
  $(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    self.keydown[keyName(event)] = true;
    return false;
  });

  $(document).bind('keyup', function (event) {
    self.keydown[keyName(event)] = false;
    return false;
  });
};

Keys.prototype.getKeys = function (callback) {
  callback(null, this.keydown);
}

module.exports = new Keys;
```

./lib/player.js
    var Keys = require('./keys')

```
var Player = function (game, keys) {
  // stuff
}

Player.prototype.update = function() {
  var self = this;
  Keys.getKeys(function(err, keys) {
    if (keys['w']) {
      self.y -= self.speed;
    }
    if (keys['a']) {
      self.x -= self.speed;
    }
    if (keys['s']) {
      self.y += self.speed;
    }
    if (keys['d']) {
      self.x += self.speed;
    }
  });
```

Comment: How `Keys` function is defined?

Comment: You will find many related issues here on SO. I always [wrote a short explanation of this problem](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/) some time ago.

Comment: @Felix Kling: now I know where to point people - because I've answered such questions here probably at least 5 times.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks, though I have to admit, it's not a very good explanation (I might improve it). I've seen quite a few questions about this, but it seems to be a bit tricky to find them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because of `Keys` has asynchronous processes in it.

It's just a known chrome issue that shows the object value by reference. So you see the object value a moment *after* you call `console.log`

To see it more clear open chrome webdev tools and put `debugger;` instead of `console.log` and see what's actually in `keydown` object. And I bet it will be just an empty object.

And I'll just leave it here: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

Comment: Sure enough, it's an empty object. Great pointer; freaking Chrome.

Comment: As a possible solution to the problem, I'm going to make my Key object an EventEmitter, if I can do that client-side (I think browserify will allow me to require('events') ..) and simply self.emit('keypress', key); or something.

Answer (score 3):

That will teach me to scan code too fast.  The comments are right and this code isn't pointing to the current problem.

The variable `this` gets reset every time you enter a new function.

```
Player.prototype.update = function () {
    var self = this;
    Keys(function (err, keydown) {
        console.log(keydown, keydown['w']);
        /* // To move a player up, for example:
          if (keydown['w']) {
            self.y += self.speed;
          }            
        */
    });
};
```

Comment: It's not about `this`. Please look at `console.log` a bit more attentive. Not an answer

Comment: @zerkms -- since I'm not a jQuery user, can you drop a hint?

Comment: it's not about jquery, look at `console.log(keydown, keydown['w']);` --- there is no `this` in this line

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - Not a jQuery issue either. The problem is that I have an object, whose properties I can see, but when I attempt to access them, they're returning undefined.

Comment: @zerkms -- Duuh... Ok, I feel like an ijiot now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any jQuery here. You need to supply more code, such as Keys source code. But I guess that you need to use http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ , for example, `keydown.which === 'w'`